# Trying to add a box with create_box, unknown Value error

Tags: python, pymunk

I'm trying to add a box to a space, here's what I have:

```
body = pymunk.Body()
body.position = 300, 200
box = pymunk.Poly.create_box(body, (100, 300))
space.add(body, box)
```

I get the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pymunk\pygame_util.py", line 153, in <listcomp>
    ps = [to_pygame(v, self.surface) for v in verts]
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pymunk\pygame_util.py", line 183, in to_pygame
    return int(p[0]), surface.get_height()-int(p[1])
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

If I do not add the body in `space.add`, I don't get the error, but then it doesn't behave properly.

It seems `p[ ]` is a vertex, but since I'm using `create_box`, I'm not specifying any vertices.

I'm very new to pymunk, and mostly new to python, so it's likely something very simple, but I've been at it for several hours and can't crack it.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like I needed to add a moment to the body, this solved the problem. I previously had a mass and no moment, assuming that defaulting to value 0 as shown in the documentation would not be problematic.

Comment: Maybe the docs should be more clear, but the reason why it defaults to 0 is that you can postpone setting mass and/or moment until later, or set it on the shapes attached to body.

Comment: @viblo That makes sense to me. Thank you.

Comment: adding moment to static body makes it fall, any help ?